# Index Match With Multiple Criteria to find cell before (Excel)

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I am looking to do a match index with a double criteria > but i want to return the results of the cell above the results.

e.g.

Two tables

[image: Table A]

[image: Table B]

Table A is the reference point and i want to reference the Invoice Number and Product Description from Table A - find them in Table B, but i want to return the Invoice number in the above cell from table B.

if i used Invoice number 987600/Product 1 from table A as an example.

The look up would find Invoice Number 9876008, find Product 1, then return invoice numerb 608034 (As it is the one above 9876008) in table B

Thank you in advance

Comment: You don't want to do an INDEX/MATCH, just do a OFFSET/MATCH. Match will return the location using the multi-criteria, then offset will return the value above it.

Answer (score 0):

Use AGGREGATE:

```
 INDEX(TABLE2!C:C,AGGREGATE(15,7,(ROW(TABLE2!$C$2:$C$100)-1)/((TABLE2!$C$2:$C$100=9876008)*(TABLE2!$F$2:$F$100="Product 1")),1))
```